# Taking Shahada with doubts

Tags: nikah, conversion, shahada

A catholic I know wishes to marry a muslim girl who has spent the past year trying to teach him about islam. He was told that he can only marry her if he is muslim, and he is willing to convert. He believes in one God, however has some doubts about the Prophet Muhammad being a prophet, although he is willing to accept that despite having these doubts. He believes that it is impossible for someone to be 100% sure about anything, but still believes more than he doubts. Would their nikkah be valid?

Comment: Well their Nikah would be invalid if he is a disbeliever and we can't pass a verdict on that relying on an incomplete and vague description from a different person. Certainty of belief is a requirement for the Shahada, if he doubts any fundamental of Islam he is a disbeliever. Just as he believes in God, Moses and Jesus, he needs to believe in Muhammad ﷺ.

Comment: Give them time to decide. But ultimately at any given moment a person should have his heart set on something eventually, but understandably can change. If he has questions then have those answered. A person shouldn't be pushed. But ultimately if he can't make his mind then it's just best to not proceed — I think

Answer (score -1):

Brother their Nikah will not be valid, in my opinion.

a) It is absolutely essential for him to have absolute faith in the Oneness of Allah AND on Muhammad (PBUH) as His last prophet, any and all doubt invalidates you from Islam as these conditions are fundamental.

b) The title of the question you pose itself is absurd - "taking Shahada with doubts", really? How can you 100% agree to something and be in doubt at the same time?

Allah knows best, wassalam!